# How can I use a 3d scene in a React Web App?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-360

I need a piece of advice. I want to create a React web application with React using typescript and I want when clicking a button to show a new page with a scene of a town. What is the best way to make it possible, I mean to integrate the scene in the React Project. I saw recently that I can use ReactVR to create a 3D scene. Is this the best way to do this or there is another way to do what I want. Please give me a piece of advice.
Thank you for reading this and for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a mixt between react-babylone and a simple canvas.
react-babylone support react hooks you will not found a problem with react versions .
There are a good community and you can find answers quickly in case of difficulty.

https://github.com/brianzinn/react-babylonjs

Answer (score 0):

I actually recommend we go with `Google's Model Viewer` library as it is the easiest if you want to 3d viewing assets. there is some other's `Three.js` and `Babylon.js` as well

https://opensea.io/assets/0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e/105652905984981711355387048174102533489553866874432653063576599426835396165633